# Cannot launch AVD manager in windows 8 using Android Studio

Tags: android-virtual-device

Cannot launch AVD manager. Output:

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system. We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads  If you
>   already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
>   variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point
>   to the JDK folder. 'D:\Android' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.  You can find the
>   complete Android SDK requirements here:
>   http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Answer (score 3):

Download the jdk from the below link ...

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

then after the installing the jdk.

**MyComputer-->Properties--->AdvancedSettings--->EnvironmentVariables**

Right Click on the **MyComputer** icon

Then select **properties**

then a windows opens  ...

In that windows see **the left pane ..**

Click **Advanced Settings**

then again a windows opens in that ...

see at the bottom . u can notice the **environment variables**

Click the environment variables

Again a windows opens ...

Then Select the **system variables**

click new button ...

then a pop up window opens ...

**Set Varible Name : JAVA
Set Variable Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin(its my path)... same way put your path the save it ...**

Then open the android studio it will open... without error